# Как в андроиде использовать протокол exchange ActiveSync

Tags: java, android, active-directory, exchange

Как в андроиде использовать протокол exchange ActivveSync ?Не могу найти ни туториал не пример , везде показывают как подключать его в почту андроида ,а я пишу свою почту как работать с этим протоколом

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxprotlp/229f77ea-6518-4fe7-84fe-bd535fc6c32e